# Wordpress: list author's posts in author.php

Tags: wordpress, list, posts, author

I want to list 10 last posts of author in author.php template.
I used this code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

But I can see only the last post of current author. Any help?

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71127/list-authors-posts-in-author-php

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

```
  <?php  global $query_string;
         query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=10' );
         while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
             <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php    endwhile;?>
```